# Why is Android Studio 4.1 Failing to Start?

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried reinstalling and deleting all android studio related folders in AppData. I am getting following error -

```
2020-11-08 22:53:27,162 [   1831]  ERROR - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Conflicting component name 'UsagesStatistic': class com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent and class com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent (componentManager=Application (containerState=ACTIVE) )
java.lang.Throwable: Conflicting component name 'UsagesStatistic': class com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent and class com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent (componentManager=Application (containerState=ACTIVE) )
        at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:146)
        at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.doAddComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:352)
        at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.initPersistenceStateComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:137)
        at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.initComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:103)
        at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreWithExtraComponents.initComponent(ComponentStoreWithExtraComponents.kt:50)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.initializeComponent$intellij_platform_serviceContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:358)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.createLightService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:598)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.getOrCreateLightService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:486)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.getLightService$intellij_platform_serviceContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:458)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.doGetService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:401)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.getService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:394)
        at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:20)
        at com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent.getInstance(UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent.java:54)
        at com.intellij.ide.gdpr.ConsentOptions.saveConfirmedConsents(ConsentOptions.java:238)
        at com.intellij.ide.gdpr.ConsentOptions.setSendingUsageStatsAllowed(ConsentOptions.java:138)
        at com.intellij.ide.gdpr.ConsentOptionsProviderImpl.setSendingUsageStatsAllowed(ConsentOptionsProviderImpl.java:14)
        at com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent.loadState(UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent.java:74)
```

Why does this happen ?

Answer (score 10):

I got resolution to this problem by editing `idea.properties` file inside Android Studio installation folder and uncommented following line -

```
idea.config.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudio/config
```

After uncommenting above line, Android Studio 4.1 started properly.

I wasted too much time resolving this issue, so posting here so it can help others.

Comment: Thanks for this. I also got a warning to set idea.plugins.path as well after applying your solution

Comment: Yes @user3689913, we have to uncomment idea.plugins.path line as well.

Though this solution gives problem while updating the Android Studio, so we need to find a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

I found the bug filed here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171901414

This worked for me:

Solved by setting "allow" to false in %%APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\options\usage.statistics.xml

Comment: In my case file was at following location - %%AppData%%\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\options\usage.statistics.xml

Answer (score 1):

Google has listed this as a known issue on their site where they recommend deleting the configuration to get back to the default state.

So if you delete %%AppData%%\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1 it should launch correctly, but you'll have to reinstall any third-party plugins.

https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#studio-config-directories

Answer (score 0):

I have removed all the settings of Android Studio that remained from previous installations in different folders. For example in Ubuntu it was under /home/username/android... Than it worked.